# How to enable pagination on vertically aligned Angular Material tabs (mat-tabs)?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-design, mat-tab

I arranged my angular material tabs vertically using CSS. Unfortunately, the pagination to navigate to the invisible tabs is not displayed

My container has a fixed height (max-height: 177px) so that only a certain number of tabs are visible. The pagination should appear when this fixed height is exceeded.

Here is my CSS / SCSS for the vertical tabs:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .mat-tab-group {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;

    .mat-tab-nav-bar,
    .mat-tab-header {
      border: 0;
    }

    .mat-tab-header {
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-end;
      max-height: 177px;
      right: 50px;
      bottom: 50px;
      z-index: 2147483647;

      .mat-tab-labels {
        flex-direction: column;
        background: gray;

        .mat-tab-label {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 20px;
          cursor: pointer;
          &:not(:last-child) {
            border-bottom: 1px solid white;
          }

          &.mat-tab-label-active {
            background-color: white !important;
            width: 100%;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    .mat-tab-body-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: table;
    }
  }
}
```

My template is structured like this:

```
<content>
  <div class="main-wrapper i-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="title">
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="end">
      <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
        <mat-tab label="{{i}}">
          <div class="device-map-container">
            <div class="device-map">
              <img id="img_equipment" [src]="apiUrl + '/path/to/svg/' + asset | sanitize">
              <a *ngFor="let data of SVGdata"
                 title="{{ data.title }}"
                 class="device-link">
              </a>
              <div class="wrapper">
                <!-- another angular component -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </mat-tab>
      </div>
    </mat-tab-group>
  </div>
</content>
```

In dev tools the templates looks like this:

```
<mat-tab-group _ngcontent-nnd-c412="" mat-align-tabs="end" animationduration="0ms" class="mat-tab-group mat-primary" ng-reflect-animation-duration="0ms">
   <mat-tab-header class="mat-tab-header" ng-reflect-selected-index="0" ng-reflect-disable-ripple="false" ng-reflect-disable-pagination="false">
      <div aria-hidden="true" mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-tab-header-pagination mat-tab-header-pagination-before mat-elevation-z4 mat-tab-header-pagination-disabled" ng-reflect-disabled="true">
         <div class="mat-tab-header-pagination-chevron"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mat-tab-label-container">
         <div role="tablist" class="mat-tab-list" style="transform: translateX(0px);">
            <div class="mat-tab-labels">
               <div role="tab" mattablabelwrapper="" mat-ripple="" cdkmonitorelementfocus="" class="mat-ripple mat-tab-label mat-focus-indicator mat-tab-label-active ng-star-inserted" id="mat-tab-label-0-0" ng-reflect-disabled="false" tabindex="0" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="2" aria-controls="mat-tab-content-0-0" aria-selected="true" aria-disabled="false">
                  <div class="mat-tab-label-content">
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div role="tab" mattablabelwrapper="" mat-ripple="" cdkmonitorelementfocus="" class="mat-ripple mat-tab-label mat-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted" id="mat-tab-label-0-1" ng-reflect-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" aria-posinset="2" aria-setsize="2" aria-controls="mat-tab-content-0-1" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                  <div class="mat-tab-label-content">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <mat-ink-bar class="mat-ink-bar" style="visibility: visible; left: 0px; width: 50px;"></mat-ink-bar>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div aria-hidden="true" mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-tab-header-pagination mat-tab-header-pagination-after mat-elevation-z4 mat-tab-header-pagination-disabled" ng-reflect-disabled="true">
         <div class="mat-tab-header-pagination-chevron"></div>
      </div>
   </mat-tab-header>
   <div class="mat-tab-body-wrapper">
      <mat-tab-body role="tabpanel" class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c380-10 mat-tab-body-active ng-star-inserted" id="mat-tab-content-0-0" ng-reflect-_content="[object Object]" ng-reflect-position="0" ng-reflect-origin="1" ng-reflect-animation-duration="0ms" aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-0-0">
         <div class="mat-tab-body-content ng-tns-c380-10 ng-trigger ng-trigger-translateTab" style="transform: none;">
            <div _ngcontent-nnd-c412="" class="device-map-container ng-star-inserted" style="">
               <div _ngcontent-nnd-c412="" class="device-map">
                  <img _ngcontent-nnd-c412="" id="img_equipment" alt="" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,...">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </mat-tab-body>
      <mat-tab-body role="tabpanel" class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c380-11 ng-star-inserted" id="mat-tab-content-0-1" ng-reflect-_content="[object Object]" ng-reflect-position="1" ng-reflect-animation-duration="0ms" aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-0-1">
         <div class="mat-tab-body-content ng-tns-c380-11 ng-trigger ng-trigger-translateTab" style="transform: translate3d(100%, 0px, 0px); min-height: 1px;">
            <!--container-->
         </div>
      </mat-tab-body>
   </div>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Currently it looks like this (6 elements are visible. But there are more than 6 tabs in the container):

[image]

Comment: Did you consider to arrange the height as the size of total tabs? This can be done by getting number of tabs, then passing the size to style..

Comment: The height of the tabs is 32x32 and a maximum of 5 tabs should be visible. From the 6th tab the pagination should appear. So the maximum height is currently set to 160px.

Comment: Ok then. Have you coded what you expect in horizontally? First of all the material should support what you desire. If it desires, then we may look how to modify it to vertical one.

Comment: @LuDeveloper The angular material tabs are paginated automatically as soon as the width of the mat-tab-header is exceeded. Everything works horizontally without any problems --> See: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

Comment: I wrote an article on :host ::ng-deep  (which is deprecated by the way), here's how you can get around it.  https://dev.to/jwp/angular-10-ng-deep-and-host-pseudo-classes-1kbg

Comment: @JohnPeters Thanks :), it's not deprecated but we should avoid it of course :). Nice article, I'll take a look.

Comment: Acutally the code is marked as deprecated but it's still usable.  The problem is that they never recommended an alternative, my article does that.

Comment: I updated the article specifically for this post.  Here's the Angular link on deprecation https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep